# fix file path according to iis

Tags: asp.net, iis, path

i have a website @local and lots of images in site, but after I deploy site to server images paths are broken(exception given in css file), and I need to fix this as soon as possible.

sample path:

```
imageurl = @"/Images/sample.gif";
```

how can i fix this?
thank you.

Comment: thx alot deepak and muhammad both of these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set a appsetting in web.config file with server url like

and get this path on code and add image name with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Images (like background-url) in CSS are always referenced relative to the css file.
```

you need to set in css file like...

```
background-image: url(  '../../Images/image.gif' );

.. this will bring out one folder from current folder hierarchy
```